# AJAX is running error function instead of success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get my database login to work.
But my AJAX call keeps running the error function instead of the success, and I am struggling to understand why.

```
function doLogin() {
    var formData = ConvertFormToJSON("#login-form");
    console.log('login data to send: ', formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/login-session.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: formData,
        success: function(logindata) {
            console.log('login data returned: ', logindata);

            var status = logindata['status'];
            if(status == "fail"){
                $("#loginerror").html(logindata['msg']);
                $("#loginerror").cs('display', 'block');
            } else {
                getUserProfileInfo();
                $("login-form").trigger('reset');
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log(jqXHR.statusText, textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

The console logs:

> login data to send:  Object {loginusername: "test", loginpassword: "test"}
>
> OK parsererror

My login-session.php code is:

```
<?php

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

$DBhost = 'localhost';
$DBuser = 'root';
$DBpass = 'root';
$DBname = 'anamadeus';

$methodType = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$data = array('status' => 'fail', 'msg' => '$methodType');

if($methodType === 'POST'){
    //Check AJAX
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

        if(isset($_POST['loginusername']) && !empty($_POST['loginusername']) && isset($_POST["loginpassword"]) && !empty($_POST["loginpassword"])){

            // get the data from the post and store in variables
            $username = $_POST["loginusername"];
            $password = $_POST["loginpassword"];

            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$DBhost;dbname=$DBname', $DBuser, $DBpass);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :log AND password = :pwd';

                $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $statement->execute(array(":log" => $username, ":pwd" => $password));

                // this should be one if there's a user by that user value and password value
                $count = $statement->rowCount();

                if($count > 0){
                    $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $returnedUsername = $rows[0]['username'];
                    $returnedPassword = $rows[0]['password'];

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $returnedUsername;
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

                    $sid=session_id();
                    $data = array("status" => "success", "sid" => $sid);
                } else {
                    $data = array("status" => "fail", "msg" => "User name and/or password not correct.");
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                $data = array("status" => "fail", "msg" => $e->getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            $data = array("status" => "fail", "msg" => "Either login or password were absent.");
        }

    } else {
        // not AJAX
        $data = array("status" => "fail", "msg" => "Has to be an AJAX call.");
    }
} else {
    // simple error message, only taking POST requests
    $data = array("status" => "fail", "msg" => "Error: only POST allowed.");
}

echo json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

?>
```

Please help me.

I am running my database and php on MAMP

Comment: Have you made sure you're not getting invalid JSON back?

Comment: the success function runs when the HTTP status code is in the `2xx` (like `200` or `201`), double check the response HTTP status in the network tab of your web browser's console

Comment: `parse error` - whatever your server is sending back ISN'T json. e.g. a php warning/error has gotten embedded before/after the json content, which makes it illegal json.

Comment: You are most likely not returning valid JSON. The keys need to be double quoted. What is being returned from the server exactly. Look at the network panel and inspect the request's response.

Comment: correct `$("#loginerror").css('display', 'block');` And don't check session, just session_start().

Comment: @epascarello: Uh, whut? The JSON is written by `json_encode`, and you can be pretty sure the output will be valid.

Comment: @epascarello THANKS YOU MUCH OBLIGED. i just changed all the single quotes to double quotes and the magic happened.

Answer (score 0):

Epascarello had the correct answer, I had to change the single quotes to double quotes.